# Custom attribute type not displaying terms in edit product - WooCommerce

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm facing an issue where:

1. I've created a custom attribute type
2. Created an attribute, called it 'test'
3. Added one term to the attribute, and called this 'Hi'
4. Go to edit the varations in edit product and I cannot seem to add any terms to it. There's just nothing there to select like normal.

[image]

This is the code I used to add a custom attribute type:

```
add_filter( 'product_attributes_type_selector', function($array){
    $array['test'] = __( 'Test', 'awcs' );
} );
```

The code is working, where it adds the type to the dropdown when creating a new attribute, it's just the variants of the attribute not displaying in the edit product page.

Comment: Try to remove that attribute from the product and add again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had that problem and resolved it alone since i could not find the answer online.
You just need to put that code inside an if. Only to run that code on attribute page.

```
if ($_GET['page']=='product_attributes') {
  add_filter( 'product_attributes_type_selector', function($array){
    $array['test'] = __( 'Test', 'awcs' );
  } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are returning anything to the filter. **Try this.**

```
add_filter("product_attributes_type_selector" , function( $array ){
    $array['test'] = __( 'Test', 'awcs' );
    return $array ;
});
```